# Grunt start Node Server and then open browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I have grunt task that starts the server:

```
module.exports = function(grunt){ 
  grunt.registerMultiTask('connect', 'Run a simple Node Server', function(){
    var options = this.options();
    // Tell Grunt this task is asynchronous.
    var done = this.async();
    var server = connect();
    server.use(function(request, response, nxt){
      ...
    });
    server.listen(port);
  });
};
```

Now I want to use grunt to start this node server first and then open the browser using grunt-open plugin.

```
grunt.task.run(['startServer', 'open']);
```

But startServer task in blocking the open task as the server keeps on listening. What should I do to keep this node server running and open the browser once the server starts?

Comment: Perhaps try `grunt.task.run(['open', 'startServer']);` ?  Worst case you have to refresh the browser.. but its likely the server would have started by the time the browser has initialised

Comment: Nopes. I want it to open after the server starts. I even tried grunt-concurrent but i am using grunt-properties-reader plugin to read server location which is causing error for grunt-concurrent plugin.

Comment: shouldn't `done` be called after server is started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. your 'connect' task currently blocks while waiting, you have to tell it to let the grunt process run asynchronously: call `done()` at the end

   ```
   ...
       server.listen(port);
       done();
   });
   ```
2. now your build will end at the end of your task list, and take down your server with it. So you have to add a task to keep it alive. I suggest using `grunt-contrib-watch`, but you may choose any one you like, as long as it's a blocking task:

   ```
   grunt.task.run(['startServer', 'open', 'watch]);
   ```

By the way, why are you calling grunt.task.run instead of defining your own task sequence `grunt.registerTask('default', ['startServer', 'open', 'watch]);` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot Xavier. Is there a way, where I can start the server separately as a different process through grunt and let the server continue running, even after the grunt stops?

Comment: I'm confused - what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Use grunt to start a daemon process? In that case you might be better served by a straight shell script to launch your process (`node yourServer.js`), optionally launched by a `grunt-shell` task.

Comment: Yes. I want to start the node server as a daemon process which should continue to listen even after all the grunt tasks are executed and closed. What I am actually trying to do is - I am running intern tests. For some of the tests, I am sending the data through node server. For this reason, I want to start the node server first and then open the browser that executes the intern tests. 
I have tried using grunt-shell but it is not async. So it is getting blocked after starting the server. For grunt-shell-spawn, there is async option, but node server shuts down after grunt tasks are completed.

Comment: This article lists multiple ways to launch a node server as a daemon: http://blog.nodejitsu.com/keep-a-nodejs-server-up-with-forever/. You should just pick one and `grunt-shell` the proper command

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as yours and I worked in Windows environment. My solution was to put the web server codes in a file for example myServer.js, and use `cmd: "start node \"path\to\myServer.js"` within the grunt-exec settings.

**Example:**

Let's assume my server file is located on the following path: `D:\SourceCodes\WebServer\myServer.js`

ip address and port of my server is `192.168.1.1:8080`,

and my webpage is `index.html`

Then the Gruntfile.js would be:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
       exec: {
           run_server:{
               cwd: "D:/SourceCodes/WebServer/",
               cmd: "start node \"D:/SourceCodes/WebServer/myServer.js\""
           },
           open_web:{                
               cmd: "start chrome http://192.168.1.1:8080/index.html"
           }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-exec');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['exec']);
}
```